Shopify Polaris js button to download a file
I'm working on my shopify app development using Polaris js, I'm trying to create a button for my subscribers to download an Excel file. I store my file in the path "app/files/file.xlsx". When I click on the button, it shows "404 Not Found". It only works if I right click on the button to open link in new tab, and the file was downloaded from xxxtrycloudflare.com.
Here is my code:
<Button variant="primary" fullWidth url="/app/files/Social.xlsx" external download accessibilityLabel="Download the file (opens a new window)">

Code reference
Browser code inspect:
<a data-polaris-unstyled="true" class="Polaris-Button Polaris-Button--pressable Polaris-Button--variantPrimary Polaris-Button--sizeMedium Polaris-Button--textAlignCenter Polaris-Button--fullWidth" aria-label="Download the file (opens a new window)" url="/app/files/Social.xlsx" download href="/app/files/Social.xlsx">


How can I change my button so that it opens the download in a new window?
